# De-serialization without protobu

Tags: protocol-buffers

Using protobuf I am able to serialize data. I need to send this serialzed packet to different location. As I know I need protobuf again to de-serialize the data.
Is there a way in which we can de-serialize data without using full protobuf library or maybe a minimum version of protobuf.

TIA...

Answer (score 0):

Once you have generated the serialization and deserialization code you don't need the protoBuff library. The ParseFromIstream() method is all you need.

From what I've read you never actually import Protobuf, you just run it to generate code that is dropped into the project. The generated code does not require the program that generated it.

Comment: protoc command is used to generate cc/h file from .proto file
Serialization to String/Stream is using a protocol. The code has to be linked to libs 
pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf
I want to know if there is a way to serialize in a form which does not require protobuf to deserialize.